# Why calling file by id is not working with jw player

Tags: php, jwplayer

I've came to an idea that looks very simple of how to hide video link to certain limit

Okay suppose we've

**index.php**

```
<?PHP

$media = 'http://www.some_site.com/get.php?id=2';

echo '<object id="mediaplayer" classid="clsid:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95" codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#version=5,1,52,701" standby="loading microsoft windows media player components..." type="application/x-oleobject" width="300" height="225">
<param name="filename" value="'.$media.'">
<param name="animationatstart" value="true">
<param name="transparentatstart" value="true">
<param name="autostart" value="true">
<param name="showcontrols" value="true">
<param name="ShowStatusBar" value="true">
<param name="windowlessvideo" value="true">
<embed type="application/x-mplayer2" src="'.$media.'" autostart="true" showcontrols="true" showstatusbar="1" bgcolor="white" width="300" height="225">
</object>';

?>
```

and **get.php** code

```
<?PHP

$id = $_GET['id'];

if ($id === '2') {

$file = "http://www.real_site.com/video/test.wmv";
echo $file;

} else {
echo "die well";
}

?>
```

so when we call `http://www.some_site.com/get.php?id=2` it will brings `http://www.real_site.com/video/test.wmv` and it worked

i've noticed that it works fine even with `youtube embedding code` `iframe` `vlc` and the ugly brothers `quicktime` `realplayer` players ... etc but not with `JW Player`

here is the code of `index.php` for case of `jwplayer`

```
<?PHP

$media = 'http://www.some_site.com/get.php?id=2';

// suppose it leads to youtube link or of what jw player support

echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='player/jwplayer.js'></script>
<div id='mediaspace'>This text will be replaced</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
'flashplayer': 'player/player.swf',
'file': '".$media."',
'controlbar': 'bottom',
'width': '300',
'height': '225',
'skin': 'player/schoon.zip'
});
</script>";

?>
```

it print this error

[image]

so is there any reason or this ! ~ that out helps me a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under:

```
'file': '".$media."',
```

Add:

```
'provider': 'video',
```

You should be all set!

Comment: Works perfect .. thats a lot .. i think i should read more about jwplayer documentations.

Comment: No problem! For JW5, since that is the version you are using, all documentation is here, for your reference - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw5/, and please mark this answer as well, thanks :-)

Comment: what if the link is youtube link !

Comment: If the link is a YouTube like, set the "provider" variable to "youtube", and you should be all set.

Answer (score 1):

You need redirect to media file instead of print file url:

```
<?PHP

$id = $_GET['id'];

if ($id === '2') {

$file = "http://www.real_site.com/video/test.wmv";
//echo $file;
header('Location: '.$file);

} else {
echo "die well";
}

?>
```